# Format currency with UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that the user will enter an amount of money. I want to set it so it will show the users current currency. I could do the following:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSNumber *someAmount = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[textField.text doubleValue]];
    NSString *string = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:someAmount];

    textField.text = string;
}
```

That works. But I want it to show on startup, and while the user is typing the amount. The above code only works when the user is finished with that textField. How can I make the code in that method to show on startup and while the user is entering numbers.

I tried to change the method to `shouldChangeTextInRange`, but it gives a weird effect.

Comment: what about adding an `-(IBAction)` and hook that up with "Value Changed" event of the textfield.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that, and I didn't get any results from the method. I tried an NSLog in that method, and nothing came up

Comment: My bad! For a `UITextField`, it should have been "Editing changed" event rather than the "Value Changed"

Comment: No problem! I tried that, and it gives me the same results as `shouldChangeTextInRange`

Comment: Try using the notification for key pressed event of keyboard.


`//set notification for when a key is pressed.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector: @selector(keyPressed:)
                                                 name: UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object: nil];
}`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Here is a sample project that might help understand what the problem is: https://jumpshare.com/b/PSW9i0N012RSgzFoW6Eb

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036971/find-locale-currency-for-iphone-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the link!! It says how to set the currency to the current one. That's only half of my question. How can I apply that to a UITextField that is editiable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReactiveCocoa you can try doing this.

```
[textField.rac_textSignal subscribeNext:^(NSString *text) {
    if (text.length < 4) text = @"0.00";

    //set currency style
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

    //leave only decimals (we want to get rid of any unwanted characters)

    NSString *decimals = [[text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    //insert decimal separator
    NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:decimals];
    [mutableString insertString:currencyFormatter.decimalSeparator atIndex:mutableString.length - currencyFormatter.minimumFractionDigits];

    //I add currency symbol so that formatter recognizes decimal separator while formatting to NSNumber
    NSString *result = [currencyFormatter.currencySymbol stringByAppendingString:mutableString];

    NSNumber *formattedNumber = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:result];
    NSString *formattedText = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:formattedNumber];

    //saving cursors position 
    UITextRange *position = textField.selectedTextRange;

    textField.text = formattedText;

    //reassigning cursor position (Its not working properly due to commas etc.)
    textField.selectedTextRange = position;
}];
```

It's not perfect, but maybe this can help you a bit in finding correct solution.