# Detect which side the current currency is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

How can I check if which side the currency symbol is at? For example, in the United States, the symbol would be like this: "`$56.58`", but in France it would be like this: "`56.58€`". So how would I be able to detect if it's on the right or left side?

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Comment: Try to find out the ASCII value of the very first and last character of the price string. If first one of them has ASCII value not in range (48-57) then currency symbol is at left side, otherwise at right side.

Comment: Can you show me a sample please?

Comment: Curious - why do you need to know this?

Comment: The reason I want this, is because I have a UITextField, and a UILabel. The label is gonna take the symbol and the textField will be an amount of money. Therefore I need to know which side the label should be on. You're probably wondering why I just skip the label and format the textField? The answer is, because it's just impossible for me to implement. I tried it for days without success. That's why I'm gonna do this "hack".

Comment: @rmaddy If you have a better solution, I'm all ears!!

Comment: No need for the label. Just use the text field with a currency formatter. If you can't make it work, post a question about it with details.

Comment: @rmaddy I asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742666/format-currency-with-uitextfield

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to format a number as currency, set the formatter's `numberStyle` to `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` and then use its `stringFromNumber:` method.

If, for some reason, you really want to know the position of the currency symbol in the format for the formatter's locale, you can ask the formatter for its `positiveFormat` and look for the character `¤` (U+00A4 CURRENCY SIGN).

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

f.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
NSLog(@"%@ format=[%@] ¤-index=%lu", f.locale.localeIdentifier, f.positiveFormat,
    (unsigned long)[f.positiveFormat rangeOfString:@"\u00a4"].location);

f.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr-FR"];
NSLog(@"%@ format=[%@] ¤-index=%lu", f.locale.localeIdentifier, f.positiveFormat,
    (unsigned long)[f.positiveFormat rangeOfString:@"\u00a4"].location);

f.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa-IR"];
NSLog(@"%@ format=[%@] ¤-index=%lu", f.locale.localeIdentifier, f.positiveFormat,
    (unsigned long)[f.positiveFormat rangeOfString:@"\u00a4"].location);
```

Result:

```
2015-06-10 21:27:09.807 commandline[88239:3716428] en-US format=[¤#,##0.00] ¤-index=0
2015-06-10 21:27:09.808 commandline[88239:3716428] fr-FR format=[#,##0.00 ¤] ¤-index=9
2015-06-10 21:27:09.808 commandline[88239:3716428] fa-IR format=[‎¤#,##0] ¤-index=1
```

Note that in the `fa-IR` case, the symbol is not the first or last character in the format string. The first character (at index zero) is invisible. It's U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK.

Comment: So would I be able to do the following: `if ([f.positiveFormat rangeOfString:@"\u00a4"].location == 0)`

Comment: The reason I want this, is because I have a UITextField, and a UILabel. The label is gonna take the symbol and the textField will be an amount of money. Therefore I need to know which side the label should be on. You're probably wondering why I just skip the label and format the textField? The answer is, because it's just impossible for me to implement. I tried it for days without success. That's why I'm gonna do this "hack".

Comment: Take a look at my update. I suppose you could do something like `if ([f.positiveFormat rangeOfString:@"\u00a4"].location  < f.positiveFormat.length / 2) ...`.