# How to add custom init for String extension?

Tags: swift, initialization

How can I add custom init method for String extension?

```
extension String {
    init(_ amount: Double, decimalPlaces: UInt) {
        self.init()
        let decimalFormat = "%0.\(String(decimalPlaces))f"
        let currencyAmount = String(format: decimalFormat, amount)
        let currencySign = NSLocalizedString("Defaults.CurrencySign", comment: "currency sign")
        let formattedString = "\(currencySign)\(currencyAmount)"
        // How to set self to `formattedString` ?
    }
}
```

As result I want to see something like this:

```
let price = Double(155.15)
let formattedPrice = String(price, decimalPlaces: 2) // formattedPrice = "$155.15"
```

**UPDATED: Final solution**

```
extension String {
    init?(currencyAmount: Double) {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: NSLocalizedString("Defaults.LocaleCurrencyFormat", comment: "currency sign")) // Defaults.LocaleCurrencyFormat equal "es_US" for US
        let formattedAmount = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: currencyAmount)) ?? ""
        self.init(formattedAmount)
    }
}
```

Comment: "*How to set self to `formattedString`*?" How do you normally perform an assignment? (*hint hint*)

Comment: @Hamish Funny enough, this didn't at all occur to me the first time I needed it. From my Java background, I was forced into a very particular, misleading mindset.

Comment: Hamish, thanks for hint :D

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev Not all locale print the currency sign before the currency magnitude.

Comment: @Alexander, yes, but currently app used only English, so it's ok. In future it'll be easy to fix.

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev I figured you were aiming for correct internationalization, given that you used `NSLocalizedString` to get the correct currency sign.

Comment: @Alexander yea, you right, fixed

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev you don't need `let  _ = currencySignLast,` in your last conditional. `if currencySignLast == true {`

Comment: Also take a look a this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency

Comment: @LeoDabus done, ty

Comment: oneliner       `self = currencySignLast == true ?  "\(currencyAmount)\(currencySign)" : "\(currencySign)\(currencyAmount)"`

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev Is there any particular reason for currencySignLast  being optional? Why don't you just assign a default value to it , `currencySignLast: Bool = false)` ? I think would be much better to use NumberFormatter so it would be naturally localized

Comment: @LeoDabus Better: `self = currencySignLast  ? currencyAmount+currencySign : currencySign+currencyAmount`

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev Not all locales use `.` for the decimal separator.

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev you should use `NSNumberFormatter `. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5039433/3141234

Comment: @LeoDabus yea, actually I already rewrite function with @BallpointBen link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960621/struggling-with-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-for-currency
Most important that now I know how to rewrite `init` methods.

Comment: @Alexander currencySignLast being optional (as it was before edit) `== true`  is required

Comment: @LeoDabus Fair point

Comment: BallpointBen, LeoDabus, Alexander, thanks, fixed with formatter :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Edit: *Don't format currencies yourself.*

However you might think currencies are formatted, you're almost certainly ***wrong***. Just compare:

- US/Canada: `$3,490,000.89`
- French Canadian: `3 490 000,89 $`
- France: `3 490 000,89 €`
- Germany: `3.490.000,89 €`

Instead, use [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) with `numberStyle` set to `.currency`, with a specified locale.

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99)!
print(priceString) // Displays $9,999.99 in the US locale
```

## Original answer:

The initializers (and mutating methods) of value types can simply assign directly to `self`:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    init(_ amount: Double, decimalPlaces: UInt) {
        let currencyAmount = String(format: "%\(decimalPlaces).f", amount)
        let currencySign = NSLocalizedString("Defaults.CurrencySign", comment: "currency sign")
        self = "\(currencySign)\(currencyAmount)"
    }
}

let price = Double(155.15)
let formattedPrice = String(price, decimalPlaces: 2) // formattedPrice = "$155.15"
```

Comment: So obvious)) Thanks, will mark as right answer after 5 min.

Comment: Using a String initializer inside a String interpolation is redundant

Comment: @LeoDabus I just copied the original code, didn't notice. Fixed.