# Use Currency format of the respective Country in Objective C

Tags: ios, macos, xcode4.2, nsnumberformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localize Currency for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856019/localize-currency-for-iphone)

I've developed an MAC App , in this app im using currency. Here im able to do in Indian rupees.
I want this app to be used globally. so i need to develop such that the user gets his respective country currency.
If i select any country den dat countries currency shud be used
I don know how to do this. Can u Please Help me if you know.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427680/iphone-how-to-get-local-currency-symbol-i-e-unstead-of-au

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code:

```
NSNumberFormatter* fmtr = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[fmtr setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSLog( @"%@", [fmtr  currencySymbol]); // Prints '$' for example
NSLog( @"%@", [fmtr internationalCurrencySymbol]); // Prints 'USD' for example
```