# xcode format numbers with spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can i convert price's in format like:

from this

> 1000000

to this

> 1 000 000

?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2233855/1679187

Comment: r u using in textfields

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik nope, i'm using labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is :

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[currency doubleValue]]];
self.label.text = numberAsString;
```

and if you want to show [with symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427680/iphone-how-to-get-local-currency-symbol-i-e-unstead-of-au/11062326#11062326)

Comment: It's show 1 000 000,00. How to remove ",00"?

Comment: perfect! i've done int with `[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];`

Comment: yes, setMaximumFractionDigits sets the maximum number of digits after the decimal.